Process hang after running sample Zenwave360 Karate project
I have cloned Zenwave360 Karate GIT repository into my local VSCode =>https://github.com/ZenWave360/karate-openapi-petstore.git
I simply clicked to run the helloWorld.feature to test it out but it seems the process hanged indefinitely at this line of code:
15:42:54.871 [Thread-0] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.Suite - [config] classpath:karate-config.js
(see attached screenshot)
Note: I have already installed ZenWave KarateIDE Classpath Jar and configure classpath globally before running the feature file
Would be great if anyone could advise how to troubleshoot this issue.
I expect that the Zenwave360 Karate should run smoothly.

Zenwave has no connection to karate labs, I don't even know if it is still in active development, I think you are better off using their github for support. if you are looking for OpenAPI support, it is being released in the Karate IntelliJ plugin next month

Hi @PeterThomas, thank you for information, I was under impression that this is the new extension to your karate framework given I observed your name as contributor in the git here https://github.com/ZenWave360/karate-ide... Do you think there is someone that I could reach out to make this sample work?

Issue solved on 31 July 2024, I simply install older version of JDK 21 (instead of using JDK 22), Karate seems to like JDK 21 so all .feature files are running smoothly now.

Issue solved on 31 July 2024, I simply installed older version of JDK 21 (instead of using JDK 22), Karate seems to like JDK 21 so all .feature files are running smoothly now!
